# Publishing issue | web 8

Tags: publishing, deployer, discovery-service, web8

I am using single publication and two Target Types/Purpose(Staging, Live)
I have setup 2 deployer, 2 discovery service for staging and live.

My issue is when I run discovery service update (java -jar .\discovery-registration.jar update) for staging, The published pages from both of the target go to staging.
When I run discovery service update (java -jar .\discovery-registration.jar update) for live, The published pages from both of the target go to live.

I have checked the config setting of deployer/discovery both have their correct path/port set for staging and Live.

Is there anything else I can check?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have separate discovery service for Staging and live (pointing to different DB) ?

Comment: Switch on debug logging for everything. Run a test and see if you get any new information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You have both discovery pointing to Same `DiscoveryDB`, When you run update for a discovery(say `staging`) then all it's capabilities get registered in this `DiscoveryDB`
- At the time of publishing to two targets, two discovery are used to determine the respective deployers but as they refer to same DB to get Deployer Capability they both use the deployer registered at that time(`staging` here) & hence they both publish to staging.

**Note-** You should use `Session-enabled Content Service` in place of `Content Service` for the Staging Enviornment if you are going to use XPM - [see here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-F89BAB09-DEA7-4AFE-BDE4-F99937929230).

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh. I have created another DB called Tridion_Broker_Staging and updated it to  cd_storage_config.xml file of discovery file. Its working now.

Comment: Great, You should also see - [why we should use different Broker & Discovery DB](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/13719/1449)